Why is publishing/building site not working after editing placeholders in Chirpy theme for Jekyll
Issue with Jekyll When Trying to Edit Chirpy Theme: Site Fails to Build After Modifying config.yml and contact.yml
I'm using the Jekyll theme called Chirpy and editing it in Visual Studio Code. So far, I've only made changes to the config.yml and contact.yml files. However, these changes seem to break the site build whenever I run the command bundle exec jekyll s to start the server.
When I revert these files to their original states, the error does not occur. I've also tried deploying the site through GitHub Pages instead of running it locally, but the problem persists.
Here's the error code I'm getting:
montyhucknall@Monty MontyHucknall.github.io % bundle exec jekyll s --trace
Configuration file: /Users/montyhucknall/Actual blog repository/MontyHucknall.github.io-1/MontyHucknall.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/montyhucknall/Actual blog repository/MontyHucknall.github.io-1/MontyHucknall.github.io
       Destination: /Users/montyhucknall/Actual blog repository/MontyHucknall.github.io-1/MontyHucknall.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/montyhucknall/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/jekyll)
/Users/montyhucknall/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/parser.rb:62:in `_native_parse': (/Users/montyhucknall/Actual blog repository/MontyHucknall.github.io-1/MontyHucknall.github.io/_data/contact.yml): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 3 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest what might be causing this problem?

So far I've tried reinstalling the dependencies, re-setting the page to the original Chirpy starter, and reformatting my changes multiple times. However, I don't think that is the problem and I'm not sure how to move forwards.

my contact.yml file
#  The contact options.

- type: github
  icon: "fab fa-github"

- type: twitter
  icon: "fa-brands fa-x-twitter"

- type: email
  icon: "fas fa-envelope"
  noblank: true # open link in current tab

- type: rss
  icon: "fas fa-rss"
  noblank: true
# Uncomment and complete the url below to enable more contact options
#
# - type: mastodon
#   icon: 'fab fa-mastodon'   # icons powered by <https://fontawesome.com/>
#   url:  ''                  # Fill with your Mastodon account page, rel="me" will be applied for verification
#
 - type: linkedin
   icon: 'fab fa-linkedin'   # icons powered by <https://fontawesome.com/>
   url:  'https://www.linkedin.com/in/monty-hucknall-719272282/'                  # Fill with your Linkedin homepage
#
# - type: stack-overflow
#   icon: 'fab fa-stack-overflow'
#   url:  ''                  # Fill with your stackoverflow homepage


can you share your contact.yml?

- type: linkedin block is indented one extra space.

Answer
- type: github
  icon: "fab fa-github"

- type: twitter
  icon: "fa-brands fa-x-twitter"

- type: email
  icon: "fas fa-envelope"
  noblank: true # open link in current tab

- type: rss
  icon: "fas fa-rss"
  noblank: true
# Uncomment and complete the url below to enable more contact options
#
# - type: mastodon
#   icon: 'fab fa-mastodon'   # icons powered by <https://fontawesome.com/>
#   url:  ''                  # Fill with your Mastodon account page, rel="me" will be applied for verification
#
- type: linkedin
  icon: 'fab fa-linkedin'   # icons powered by <https://fontawesome.com/>
  url:  'https://www.linkedin.com/in/monty-hucknall-719272282/'                  # Fill with your Linkedin homepage
#
# - type: stack-overflow
#   icon: 'fab fa-stack-overflow'
#   url:  ''                  # Fill with your stackoverflow homepage

Remove indentation for - type: linkedin

Simply remove the indenting on
- type: linkedin
   icon: 'fab fa-linkedin'   # icons powered by <https://fontawesome.com/>
   url:  'https://www.linkedin.com/in/monty-hucknall-719272282/'

